# Execute SQL statement in managed bean

Tags: java, sql, jsf, javabeans

I have this managed bean which makes SQL queries to Oracle database and returns content of the variables SessionTTL, MAXACTIVEUSERS and ACTIVEUSERS. After that the variables content is displayed in JSF page.

My questions are is this a current way to fetch multiple results from SQL query and what is the connect way to utilize the `GetVariablesDB()` method just after the bean is loaded. This code below will display null variables because the method `GetVariablesDB()` is not called.

P.S I edited the code

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
   // or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include package for SHA-256 encryption */
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
   // or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;   

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("DashboardController")

@SessionScoped

public class Dashboard implements Serializable {

    private  String storedPassword = null;               
    private  String stringzoro = null;    
    private  String stringone = null;
    private  String stringtwo = null;
    private  String SQL_Statement = null;


       public Dashboard() throws SQLException{    
           GetVariablesDB();
       }

       /* Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
       @Resource(name="jdbc/Oracle")
       private DataSource ds;


       public String getUser(){
           return stringzoro;       
       }

       public String getPassword(){
           return stringone;
       }




       private void GetVariablesDB() throws SQLException {          

            if (ds == null) throw new SQLException();      
       Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            if (conn == null) throw new SQLException();      

       try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
                try {
                       SQL_Statement = "SELECT * from GLOBALSETTINGS";

                       PreparedStatement passwordQuery = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_Statement);

                       ResultSet result = passwordQuery.executeQuery();

                       if(result.next()){
                            stringzoro= result.getString("SessionTTL");
                            stringone = result.getString("MAXACTIVEUSERS");
                            stringtwo = result.getString("ACTIVEUSERS");                            
                       }

                       conn.commit();
                       committed = true;
                 } finally {
                       if (!committed) conn.rollback();
                       }
            }
                finally {               
                conn.close();

                }  

       }                         
}
```

Now when I try to execute the bean I get this error stack in glassfish:

```
[#|2012-03-08T18:37:44.233+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=3393;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Deleted /tmp/osgiapp6154116770873802943|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:44.233+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=3393;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Undeployed bundle com.DX_57.SM_57 [275]|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:44.234+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=3393;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Stopped com.DX_57.SM_57 [275]|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:44.240+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=3393;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Uninstalled com.DX_57.SM_57 [275]|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:44.432+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=3398;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|com.sun.webui.jsf.component.DropDown::The current value of component propertyForm:deployTable:topActionsGroup1:filter does not match any of the selections. 
Did you forget to reset the value after changing the options? |#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.363+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=3942;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.458+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=3942;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.459+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=3942;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.527+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Installed com.DX_57.SM_57 [276] from reference:file:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.540+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Started com.DX_57.SM_57 [276]|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.569+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=68;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT was successfully deployed in 96 milliseconds.|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:54.614+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Expanded at file:/tmp/osgiapp8052165052141203090/|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.059+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgiweb|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|total number of classes with faces annotation = 0|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.083+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT'|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.093+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgiweb|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Faces Config uris excluding the ones named as faces-config.xml = []|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.141+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgiweb|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Facelet Config uris = []|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.142+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Monitoring jndi:/server/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.165+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0671: Loading application [com.DX_57.SM_57_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] at [/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT]|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.183+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgiweb|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Registered ServletContext as a service with properties: {osgi.web.symbolicname=com.DX_57.SM_57, osgi.web.version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT, osgi.web.contextpath=/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT} |#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:37:55.186+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|deployed bundle com.DX_57.SM_57 [276] at file:/tmp/osgiapp8052165052141203090/|#]

[#|2012-03-08T18:38:03.560+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application|_ThreadID=322;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error Rendering View[/Settings.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.DX_57.SM_57.Dashboard.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderHeader(TableRenderer.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
    at com.DX_57.SM_57.Dashboard.GetVariablesDB(Dashboard.java:70)
    at com.DX_57.SM_57.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    ... 55 more
|#]
```

Is this Java code for SQL statement correct?

Comment: well, you could use the `GetVariablesDB` method in the construct or do a inner call to this function in your jsp

Comment: can you add the line numbers of the `GetVariablesDB()` method in your actual code?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/wBDMnTHb

Comment: the error marks the line 70 and that's an empty line, very odd

Comment: Maybe you should catch your exception and print out the full stacktrace! Thats a new question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call GetVariablesDB() in your constructor. Why are your instance variables and the method public?

If you need that Data at startup of your site then you should initialize the data in your constructor, else call the public method at a specific event.

And for better readability you should use the this keyword or atleast mark your instance variables using a naming convention. Its hard to follow code if you cannot distinguish the scope of the variables by their name or access modifier.